# "Stack overflow (deep)" error in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create a function `prime-factors` that returns the prime factors of a number. To do so, I created `is-prime` function, and `prime-factors-helper` that will do a recursive check of the prime factors.

```
(defun is-prime (n &optional (d (- n 1))) 
  (if (/= n 1) (or (= d 1)
          (and (/= (rem n d) 0)
               (is-prime  n (- d 1)))) ()))

(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
   (if (is-prime x) (list x) 
        (if (is-prime n) 
            (if (AND (= (mod x n) 0) (< n (/ x 2)))
                (append (list n) (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) (+ 1 n)))
                (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))       
            (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))

(defun prime-factors (x)
    (prime-factors-helper x 2))
```

The main function which is `prime-factors` seem to work for some numbers. However for big numbers it returns `"Stack overflow (deep)"`.

```
CL-USER 44 : 5 > (prime-factors 66)
(2 3 11)

CL-USER 49 : 5 > (prime-factors 512)
"Stack overflow (deep)"
```

Can you please tell me why is it returning this error? is there something wrong with the recursive call?

**[UPDATE]**

I redefined the `is-prime` function but apparently it is not the problem.

```
(defun is-prime (x &optional (i 2))
    (if (= x 1) nil
        (if (or (= x 2) (= x 3)) t
            (if (<= i (sqrt x))
                (if (= (mod x i ) 0) nil
                    (is-prime x (+ i 1)))
                t))))



(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
   (if (is-prime x) 
       (list x) 
       (if (is-prime n) 
            (if (AND (= (mod x n) 0) (<= n (/ x 2)))
                (cons n (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) n))
                (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))       
            (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))
```

**Optimisation question**

I have another problem of optimisation. When I have a big number such as `123456789`, I get this error message `Stack overflow (stack size 261120)`. I believe because since the correct answer is `(3 3 3607 3803)`, my program once it constructs the list with the two first elements `(3 3)`, it will take so long to find the next prime factor. How can I optimise my code?

Comment: That means your recursion isn't stopping. The only time you seem to stop recursing is when x is prime. If that never happens, the recursion will go on forever. Have you tested `is-prime` to make sure it's correct?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes I tested it. It is correct

Comment: @Carcigenicate it is not the `is-prime` function. I defined it differently but still I have the exact same problem. Please check the new update where I put the new definition of the `is-prime` function

Comment: Then you'll need to find out why the recursion isn't stopping. `(prime-factors 512)` could also just be "too big" of a problem to solve using unoptimized recursion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I solved it. Actually it does not only that for 512. It happens for all the multiples of 2. In the condition `(if (AND (= (mod x n) 0) (< n (/ x 2)))` if the number is multiple of 2 it will never enter this condition even though it has to. The reason is that I put `<`. It should be `<=`. So `(if (AND (= (mod x n) 0) (<= n (/ x 2)))`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you solved it. I know Clojure, but not CL. I had a hard time trying to read your code, so without running it, I couldn't really follow the execution. You could post an answer outlining your debugging and what the solution turned out to be.

Comment: I added `(trace prime-factors prime-factors-helper)`, and for values over 23, ie. `(prime-factors 24)`, the `n` seems to increase forever, for no reason.

Comment: @coredump can you please check my question on how to optimise my function for big numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352407/how-can-i-optimise-my-recursive-lisp-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some general remarks about your code:**

```
(defun is-prime (x &optional (i 2))
    (if (= x 1) nil
        (if (or (= x 2) (= x 3)) t
            (if (<= i (sqrt x))
                (if (= (mod x i ) 0) nil
                    (is-prime x (+ i 1)))
                t))))

(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
   (if (is-prime x) (list x) 
        (if (is-prime n) 
            (if (and (= (mod x n) 0) (<= n (/ x 2)))
                (append (list n) (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) (+ 1 n)))
                (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))       
            (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))


(defun prime-factors (x)
    (prime-factors-helper x 2)) 

CL-USER 44 : 5 > (prime-factors 66)
(2 3 11)
```

A few things you should improve: indentation, code formatting, proper use of the REPL and choice of Lisp functions:

**Code indentation and formatting**

Let's start with indentation and formatting. The usual indentation would be:

```
(defun is-prime (x &optional (i 2))
  (if (= x 1)
      nil
    (if (or (= x 2) (= x 3))
        t
      (if (<= i (sqrt x))
          (if (= (mod x i ) 0)
              nil
            (is-prime x (+ i 1)))
        t))))

(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
  (if (is-prime x)
      (list x) 
    (if (is-prime n) 
        (if (and (= (mod x n) 0) (<= n (/ x 2)))
            (append (list n) (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) (+ 1 n)))
          (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))
      (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))


(defun prime-factors (x)
  (prime-factors-helper x 2))
```

**Improving the code**

Now we can rewrite the first two functions:

Use `case` to compare for numbers and then you can rewrite the `if` expression to a logic expression using `or`, `and` and `not`.

```
(defun is-prime (x &optional (i 2))
  (case x
    (1     nil)
    ((2 3) t)
    (t     (or (not (<= i (sqrt x)))
               (and (/= (mod x i) 0)
                    (is-prime x (+ i 1)))))))
```

Next we reduce the indentation level by using `cond`.

`(append (list foo) bar)` is just `(cons foo bar)`.

We also can get rid of one `if`.

```
(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
  (cond ((is-prime x)
         (list x))
        ((and (is-prime n)
              (= (mod x n) 0)
              (<= n (/ x 2)))
         (cons n (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) (+ 1 n))))
        (t (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))
```

**Test function**

Now we need to test it:

```
(defun test (&optional (n 20))
  (loop for i from 2 below n
        for factors = (prime-factors i)
        do (print (list i
                        (= (reduce #'* factors) i)
                        (cons '* factors)))))
```

**There is a problem: fix it!**

As you can see there is a problem left... I had to break the code from an endless loop when we compute the factors for 8.

```
CL-USER 51 > (test)

(2 T (* 2)) 
(3 T (* 3)) 
(4 T (* 2 2)) 
(5 T (* 5)) 
(6 T (* 2 3)) 
(7 T (* 7)) 
Break.
  1 (continue) Return from break.
  2 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.
```

But that one is easy to fix and left as an exercise.

**The REPL.**

When you have a prompt like this in LispWorks

```
CL-USER 44 : 5 >
```

it means that you are five (!) levels deep in breaks.

Time to get to the top-level repl by entering the `:top` command:

```
CL-USER 44 : 5 > :top

CL-USER 45 >
```

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I have already fixed the problem of the multiples of 2, I only forgot to post it. However, I discovered another problem of optimisation. Can you please check my new question in my post.

Comment: @Benz: make a new question, don't add to an existing one

Comment: I just did. Can you please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352407/how-can-i-optimise-my-recursive-lisp-function